# CSS properties not updating in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am not sure if you know but I edit some CSS by setting the display to block but after being updated in the domain it says (according to the inspector) that the display is table-cell. (works fine when the page is locally opened from the computer)

I have a few images that can prove it. One in the Notepad++ editor and one in the Chrome inspector.
[image]
[image]

Is it a glitch? or what am I doing wrong?


I say Chrome because I tried it on Firefox and it worked by setting the display property to block.

Comment: Cached? Clear / disable cache.

Comment: It worked! Thanks